# Woocommerce- Remove product categories from url

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We are currently using rank math to do redirects and remove soms slugs out of the URL. Our redirect are now done by our hosting company. So we like to remove rank math from Wordpress. We know there are plugins but we would like to hardcode it in our functions.php.

The only function I can't get my head around it is how I can remove the parent product-categories out of the url. So our url is like this:

```
https://staging-lichtgeluidhurennl.kinsta.cloud/overig/verbruiksmateriaal/tape-batterijen/
```

and needs to be:

```
https://staging-lichtgeluidhurennl.kinsta.cloud/tape-batterijen/
```

Anyone that can help me with this or at least can point me in the right direction.

Kind Regards.

Comment: 'tape-batterijen' is a category?

Comment: Please see: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6106/remove-parent-category-from-permalink-basically-only-have-the-child-category

Comment: @RobyRajuOommen yes this is a product-category aswell. We only want to remove the parent product-categories.

Comment: Hope the link I shared answers your question then :)

Comment: unfortunately these are normal categories. I am talking about product categories from woocommerce. I am Sorry if this wasn't clear in my question.